# How do I use JavaScript to make a onmouseover css animation don't reset when I stop hovering?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Sorry for the big title, but I made a spinning animation with a image using css, so when I hover my mouse over it, the image spins. The thing is, I wanted it to not reset when I'm not hovering anymore.

```
HTML:
<img src="dieimg.png" class="die" width="50" height="50" id="die">

CSS:
@keyframes spin {
  from {transform:rotate(0deg);}
  to {transform:rotate(360deg);}
}
.die:hover {
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  animation: 1s spin;
}
.die {
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
}
```

I'm new to JavaScript (and to html and css as well, but not as much) and I would appreciate if you could give me something so I can understand the code better, as well as the code for it.

Comment: You'll need to start the animation via JavaScript instead of CSS when the `mouseover` event occurs.

Comment: Would you have the code and some explanations?

Comment: See the referenced answer for that.

Comment: But where's the code? I only see what I need to do, but I don't know how to do it...